# how to inject dependencies to a service with MacWire (play framework)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, macwire

I have a service class, and the service have one method `getSomethingFromApi` , now , I want to have play Configuration instance so I can pull stuff from the application.conf, and a play WSClient so I can perform http calls.

this is how I want my service to look:

```
class MyApiService {

  def getSomethingFromApi(whichApi: String): Future[ApiRes] = {
    wsClient.url(configuration.getString(whichApi)).withHttpHeaders(("Content-Type", "application/json")).get.map { res =>
      response.status match {
        case Status.OK => // do something
        case _ => throw new Exception
      }
    }
  }

}
```

and this is the ServicesModule that is wiring my services:

```
import com.softwaremill.macwire._

trait ServicesModule {

  lazy val myService: MyApiService = wire[MyApiService]

}
```

my question now is what is the right way of using wiring play Configuration and WSClient instances..? cause currently i need those instances in my service but i dont have them, how should i do this the right way?
thanks

Comment: `class MyApiService @Inject() (ws: WSClient)`

Comment: @erip but how the Service module passing this injected dependences? And is it macwire @Inject()? Cause if not it will be evaluated at runtime no? I want to keep it pure macwire manual di

Answer (score 0):

With macwire it'll probably look like this

```
// MyApiService.scala
class MyApiService(wsClient: WSClient) { ... }

// ServicesModule.scala
trait ServicesModule with NingWSComponents {
    lazy val wsClient = wire[WSClient]
    lazy val apiService = wire[MyApiService]
}
```

I haven't tried using macwire with play myself, so I have relatively low confidence that it'll work on the first try, but macwire play example suggests [mixing in certain Play modules](https://github.com/adamw/macwire/blob/master/examples/play24/app/com/softwaremill/play24/AppApplicationLoader.scala#L26-L31) to provide values needed for WSClient. Most likely not all of them are needed, but some might be - soo I'd suggest starting with just `NingWSComponents` and gradually adding more until it works.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) if I do something like that, how can I access wsClient and apiService from MyApiService..? im suppose to extend ServicesModule?

Comment: @jackmiao `apiService` is an instance of `MyApiService`, so you don't access it there. Accessing `wsClient` from `MyApiService` is straightforward - it is one of the constructor parameters, so you just do `wsClient.url(...)` there.

Answer (score 0):

For the configuration I suggest using something like [PureConfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig) and load the configuration as follows

```
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures

case class YourConfClass(name: String, quantity: Int)

val config: Either[pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderFailures,YourConfClass] = loadConfig[YourConfClass]
```

This then can be passed on to any component of your app using macwire.

As of Play 2.6.X one should use `AhcWSComponents` that are provided by the `ws` dependency as follows:

In your build.sbt file add the ws dependency to your project

```
libraryDependencies += ws
```

In your module trait mix-in the `AhcWSComponents` trait and wire the `WSClient`

```
trait ServicesModule with AhcWSComponents {
    lazy val wsClient = wire[WSClient]
    lazy val apiService = wire[MyApiService]
}
```

In your `MyApiServic`e add the `WSClient` as a param. to the constructor

```
class MyApiService(wsClient: WSClient) { ... }
```

And now you're done. This general rule applies to all provided dependencies.