# Fail to wire play dependancies with Macwire

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection, playframework, macwire

i have a api service class that is dependent on play's Configuration and WSClient instancees.

and I dont want to use @Inject() anotation cause I want to use compile-time injection with Macwire so what i did is this:

```
// this is a trait that here im wiring all the dependencies that my api service needs
trait ApiDependencies {

  lazy val conf: Configuration = wire[Configuration]
  lazy val wsc: WSClient = wire[WSClient]

}


// this is the api service

class ApiService extends ApiDependencies {

  def getInfo (id: String): Future[Option[Info]] = {
    wsc.url("...").withHttpHeaders(("Content-Type", "application/json")).get.map { response =>
      response.status match {
        case Status.OK => ...
        case Status.NO_CONTENT => ...
        case _ => throw new Exception()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I get a compiler error:

> Error: Cannot find a value of type: [com.typesafe.config.Config]
>   lazy val conf: Configuration = wire[Configuration]
>
> Error: Cannot find a public constructor nor a companion object for
>   [play.api.libs.ws.WSClient]   lazy val wsc: WSClient = wire[WSClient]

does someone knows how can I solve this issue...? and why is it happening :/

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to inject dependencies to a service with MacWire (play framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875361/how-to-inject-dependencies-to-a-service-with-macwire-play-framework)

Answer (score 0):

`Configuration` is a playframework Configuration, which [internally uses](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Configuration.scala#L174) Typesafe's [Config library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config). Quoting [Playframework docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfigFile#Configuration-file-syntax-and-features):

> The configuration file used by Play is based on the [Typesafe config library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)

The exception you're getting tells you exactly this - macwire is unable to create an instance of `Configuration` as there are no `Config` instance in scope.

To fix it, you obviously need to provide such instace. Simplest way to do so would probably look like this:

```
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
trait ApiDependencies {
    lazy val configuration: Config = ConfigFactory.load()
    lazy val conf: Configuration = wire[Configuration]
}
```

Note that `ConfigFactory.Load()` basically uses default configuration file (`application.conf`) and it **does** take into account configuration overriding techniques described in [Play's Configuration docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfigFile), as it is actually provided by typesafe config library (from Typesafe Config GitHub readme):

> users can override the config with Java system properties, java -Dmyapp.foo.bar=10

---

Regarding `WSClient`: this is due to the fact that `WSClient` is not a class, but [a trait](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WSClient.scala#L21). You need to wire actual implementation, i.e. `NingWSClient`, like this:

```
trait ApiDependencies {
  lazy val conf: Configuration = wire[Configuration]
  lazy val wsc: WSClient = wire[NingWSClient]
}
```

See [`WSClient`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.8/api/java/play/libs/ws/WSClient.html) scaladoc for list of implementing classes (under "All Known Implementing Classes") - by the time of writing there are only `NingWSClient` and `AhcWSClient`. Which one is better is a different (and potentially opinion-based question).

Comment: do you have an answer for the WSClient error...in getting this too :/ @J0HN

Comment: @JohnBigs I've updated the answer - please take a look and let me know if it helps