# why I cant extend playFrameworks NingWSComponents? (play 2.6.0)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

From what I understand, to use `WSClient` instance you need to mix `NingWSComponents`, like this guy answer here [how to inject dependencies to a service with MacWire (play framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875361/how-to-inject-dependencies-to-a-service-with-macwire-play-framework).

But this dosent work...intellij is not recognizing NingWSComponents

also this guy use it here http://loicdescotte.github.io/posts/play24-compile-time-di/

its really weird...

thankks